# Why Masjid-e-Diraar been burnt?

Tags: prophet-muhammad, history, masjid

I want to know that why Rasoolullah (Sallallahu Alaihi Wasallam) once actually ordered the Blessed Sahaabah to burn and demolish a Masjid (mosque) known as **Masjid-e-Diraar**?

Comment: Citing that Hadith which talks about this issue, would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In the name of Allah, the most Compassionate, the most Merciful**

---

Paying attention to the verse below (Tu’bah: 107) could be helpful and useful in regarding the disadvantages of that Masjib (mosque)

> وَالَّذِينَ اتَّخَذُوا مَسْجِدًا ضِرَارًا وَكُفْرًا وَتَفْرِيقًا
> بَيْنَ الْمُؤْمِنِينَ وَإِرْصَادًا لِّمَنْ حَارَبَ اللَّـهَ
> وَرَسُولَهُ مِن قَبْلُ ۚ وَلَيَحْلِفُنَّ إِنْ أَرَدْنَا إِلَّا
> الْحُسْنَىٰ ۖ وَاللَّـهُ يَشْهَدُ إِنَّهُمْ لَكَاذِبُونَ ﴿١٠٧
>
> And [there are] those [hypocrites] who took for themselves a mosque
> for causing harm and disbelief and division among the believers and as
> a station for whoever had warred against Allah and His Messenger
> before. And they will surely swear, "We intended only the best." And
> Allah testifies that indeed they are liars. (107)

Hence it shows that they (Monafeqin or hypocrites) built that mosque to

- harm the Moslems,
- to circulate the kufr there,
- making differences between believers

  and so forth.

---

**References:**

- [tanzil.net](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sahih/9:107)
- [www.maarefislam.com](http://www.maarefislam.com/doreholomvamaarefislam/bookscontent/imamshenasi/imam10/imam10.14.htm)